# using async data in my page using nuxtjs

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I have read using async data or fetch is a better approach in pages in nuxtjs instead of using the created hook.

I am struggling to get my code to work though

I had the following (Which does work fine)

```
created () {
  this.$store.dispatch('cases/getCase', this.$route.params.caseId );
},
```

But how would I change that to work with the async method instead please, and be able to return more than one state when I need to.

I tried the following

```
     async asyncData ({ params }) {
        const thisCase = await this.$store.dispatch('cases/getCase', this.$route.params.caseId );
// constant thisUser
        return { thisCase }
// return { thisCase, thisUser}
      },
```

but this generated an error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.$store')

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` not available in asyncData/fetch. It is even stated in [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/) in special orange warning.

> You do NOT have access of the component instance through this inside
>   asyncData because it is called before initiating the component.

And again as said in docs

> method receives the context object as the first argument, you can use
>   it to fetch some data and return the component data.

Context is where from you should be getting your store. [Here docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context) for context.

So your code would be

```
 async asyncData ({ params, store }) {
    const thisCase = await store.dispatch('cases/getCase', params.caseId )
    return { thisCase }
  },
```